# Vue can't receive subscribe to event from child component in to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have two components - parent and child. The child emits an event, which should trigger a console output in a parent component. However nothing is printed in console.

**TestPage.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div v-on:hidden="hiddenEvent">

    <TestComponent></TestComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import TestComponent from "@/app/test/TestComponent";
export default {
  name: "TestPage",
  components: {TestComponent},


  methods:  {
    hiddenEvent()  {
      console.log("hiddenEvent");
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**TestComponent.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div class="test-container" v-if="!isHidden"
        v-on:click="this.flip">
    {{this.text}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TestComponent",

  data() {
    return {
      text: "abc",
      isHidden: false
    }
  },

  methods:  {
    flip()  {
      this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;

      if (this.isHidden)  {
        this.$emit("hidden");
      } else  {
        this.$emit("revealed");
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

.test-container  {
  padding: 2em;

  background-color: #2EAC68;
}

</style>
```

When I click on the `abc`:

[image]

it disappears:

[image]

So I know the `flip` method is executed. However the parent's `hiddenEvent` is not executed, because `hiddenEvent` is never printed to console.

What am I doing wrong? I need the parent `TestPage` to be able to react to the event emitted  by the child `TestComponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `v-on:hidden="hiddenEvent"` on `TestComponent` tag not on the wrapping div.

The

```
<TestComponent></TestComponent>
```

in `TestPage.vue` should be updated to:

```
<TestComponent v-on:hidden="hiddenEvent"></TestComponent>
```

See in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-artem-mdn38u)

Comment: But I need the parent `TestPage` to be able to react to the event emitted  by the child `TestComponent`

Comment: I mean in the TestPage component it should be `<TestComponent v-on:hidden="hiddenEvent"></TestComponent>`

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I edited your answer to make it easier to understand

Comment: @parsecer I added a sandbox sample too

Answer (score 1):

You are listening to event from the child so put it on the child:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  methods:  {
    hiddenEvent()  {
      console.log("hiddenEvent");
    }
  }
})
app.component('testComponent', {
  template: `
    <div class="test-container" v-if="!isHidden"
        v-on:click="this.flip">
    {{this.text}}
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      text: "abc",
      isHidden: false
    }
  },
  methods:  {
    flip()  {
      this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
      if (this.isHidden)  {
        this.$emit("hidden");
      } else  {
        this.$emit("revealed");
      }
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.test-container  {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #2EAC68;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div >
    <test-component @hidden="hiddenEvent"></test-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple example for future readers:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-breeze-zr6cun?file=/src/Child.vue

**App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child v-on:childEvent="executeChildEvent($event)" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Child: Child,
  },

  methods: {
    executeChildEvent(data) {
      alert("hello " + data);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
}
</style>
```

**Child.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="child" v-on:click.stop="this.$emit('childEvent', 0)">Child</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
#child {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 2em;
}
</style>


<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",

  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```